# Dataframe with object data type but Float values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with year column which has mixed data types. it looks like this:

```
Year  #(the dtype is Object)
'2001'
2002.0
2003.0
```

and so on

I want to keep the data type but change the data to look like the first value.

```
Year
2001, 2002,2003,2004 .......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str).str.split('.').str[0]
```

or

```
df['Year'] = df['Year'].astype(str).str.extract(r'(\d+)', expand=False)
```